# Asterisks Dialplan Extensions

Tags: asterisk, sip

I'm playing around with a very simple asterisks setup. My asterisks server is 192.168.1.10 (Ubuntu 12.04), my 2 sip clients are 192.168.1.20 and .21 (both using ubuntu 12.04 and Jitsi as a sip client). I have 2 users (user1 and user2) who can successfully register with the asterisks server. I followed this guide here https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Creating+SIP+Accounts for setting up the sip.conf and extensions.conf with a few changes to use tcp instead of udp. However I'm having issues getting my dial plan extensions to work..

Here's my sip.conf

```
[general]
tcpenable=yes
tcpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
transport=tcp

[friends_internal](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=local
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
transport=tcp

[user1](friends_internal)
secret=password
transport=tcp

[user2](friends_internal)
secret=password
transport=tcp
```

My extensions.conf is pretty much default except at the bottom I added this:

```
[users]
exten => 6001,1,Dial,SIP/user1,20
exten => 6002,1,Dial,SIP/user2,20
```

From an asterisks prompt, if I do a 'dialplan show users' I get "There is no existence of 'users' context.

I can confirm that I have 2 clients/phones connected with 'sip show peers'

```
Name/username     Host             Dyn Forceport  ACL    Port     Status
user1/user1      192.168.1.20       D     N       43874     Unmonitored
user2/user2      192.168.1.21       D     N       38740     Unmonitored
```

I can manually add the 2 extensions at an asterisks prompt to the local call plan with this however they are not persistent when the asterisks server is restarted:

```
dialplan add extension 6001,1,Dial,SIP/user1,20 into local
dialplan add extension 6002,1,Dial,SIP/user2,20 into local
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in your Configuration.

1. The context defined in `friends_internal` is set to `local`. According to your dialplan, it should be set to `users`.
2. As far as I know, the dialplan should be build like this

   ```
   exten => 6001,1,Dial(SIP/user1, 20)
   exten => 6002,1,Dial(SIP/user2, 20)
   ```